# Function to check whether a combination of letters appears in a sequence of random words and determine where exactly are they

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I created a function in javascript to generate a random string with a certain length in either uppercase/lowercase or both.

```
    function randomString(max, option) {
      var rNum = [];
      if (option.toLowerCase() === "lowercase") {
        for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97) + 97);
          rNum.push(randomNumber);
        }
      } else if (option.toLowerCase() === "uppercase") {
        for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 65) + 65);
          rNum.push(randomNumber);
        }
      } else if (option.toLowerCase() === "both") {
        for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 65) + 65);
          while ([91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96].includes(n)) {
            //If the random number is between 90 and 97 then we keep generating new numbers:
            n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 65) + 65);
          }
          rNum.push(n);
        }
      } else {
        return "Second parameter not valid, please type 'lowercase','uppercase' or 'both'";
      }
      var word = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < rNum.length; i++) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(rNum[i]);
        word += letter;
      }
      return word;
    }
```

Now I wanted to create a second function that given any string from the user, it checks whether that word appears in the randomly generated string.

I started it and honestly I simply have no idea how to do it. How do I check where in that long string there is indeed the word which I don't know how long it is. I guess it can see if it does exist or not, but how do i find its position? I tried using `array.indexOf(userString)`, but it only returns the first time it appears.

```
function findWordsByChance(letters) {
  var myString = randomString(999999, "both");
  var splited = myString.split("");
  if (splited.includes(letters)) {
    console.log("this combination exists");
  } else {
    console.log("it doesnt");
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < splited.length - 1; i++) {
    //check where it is (??)
  }
}
findWordsByChance("Hi");
```

I'm still quite new to programming, so give me a break if I made any stupid mistakes :)
btw, if you guys got any tips on how to do something I already did but in a more efficient way, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple .match() function in javascript to find a string in another string.

```
var myString = randomString(100, "both");
// myString = "fAuqxBfkXprhvRqOGLPmTiFbhrZtjXXMFwircAGBBtIkiDbGHPvYymMlabJyeAKUtIYNedUpNPlaeEcjIsSeEtOUriHTuCtbpNZX"

var result = myString.match('rZtjX');
// result[0] is your search string...the "letters" value
// result[1] is where the string was found

// If you want to get all occurrences where the search string was found you can use the function below. 

findOccurrences = (needle, haystack) => {
    const pieces = haystack.split(needle);
    if (!pieces.length) {
        return console.log('No Matches');
    }
    let index = 0;
    pieces.forEach((piece) => {
        index += piece.length;
        console.log(needle, ' found at ', index);
        index += needle.length;
    });
}
findOccurrences('LPmT', myString);
LPmT  found at  17
LPmT  found at  47
LPmT  found at  81
LPmT  found at  99
LPmT  found at  112
```

Comment: but this .match() function only gives the position of the first appearance, right? So it's pretty much like indexOf();

Comment: @VinyZiks Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) accepts a second parameter which defines a start offset, so you can use this to loop through and find every occurrence. You just need to make the start point immediately past the last occurrence for each iteration. Here's how I'd write the function:

```js
function indexOfAll(needle, haystack) {
  var indices = [];
  var index = 0;
  while ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index)) > -1) {
    indices.push(index);
    index += needle.length;
  }
  return indices;
}

console.log(indexOfAll("oat", "goat in a boat"));
```

...but this may be easier for you to read:

```js
function indexOfAll(needle, haystack) {
  var indices = [];

  var offset = 0;
  while (haystack.indexOf(needle, offset) > -1) {
    var indexOfThisOccurrence = haystack.indexOf(needle, offset);
    indices.push(indexOfThisOccurrence);
    offset = indexOfThisOccurrence + needle.length;
  }

  return indices;
}

console.log(indexOfAll("ug", "slug in a mug"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn their input into a regex.

```
const inputRegex = new RegExp(input, 'g')
```

Then you *could* use `string.matchAll()` to get all instances of matches.

```
const matches = randomLetters.matchAll(inputRegex)
```

But that gives you an iterator. To have it as an array, you'd do this instead:

```
const matches = [...randomLetters.matchAll(inputRegex)]
```

Now, each item in matches is an object with a key `index` referring to its position on the string.

You can [learn more at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: Nice and simple solution, but be aware that this is still considered experimental, so it is not compatible with internet explorer, microsoft edge, safari, or safari mobile.